# merge xml - bring element names from doc b into doc a as attribute values, match on child text (or position?)

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt, xslkey

*Hello and thanks in advance for any advice!*

**XML A**
Metadata export a
Element names are custom, reflecting local field names
Element child text identical to B in content, document order

```
<metadata>
   <record>
      <Title>Untitled</Title>
      <Photographer>Gordon Parks</Photographer>
      <Notes>An important photograph because (...)</Notes>
   </record>
   ...
</metadata>
```

**XML B**
Metadata export b
Element names reflect configured mapping to Dublin Core Elements/Terms
Element child text identical to A in content, document order

```
<metadata>
   <record>
      <title>Untitled</title>
      <creator>Gordon Parks</creator>
      <description>An important photograph because (...)</description>
   </record>
   ...
</metadata>
```

**Desired output**
Use local field names as element names
Capture DC Elements/Terms as @dc values

```
<metadata>
   <record>
      <Title dc="title">Untitled</Title>
      <Photographer dc="creator">Gordon Parks</Photographer>
      <Notes dc="description">An important photograph because (...)</Notes>
   </record>
   ...
</metadata>
```

**Stylesheet as of now**

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <metadata>
            <xsl:for-each select="XML_A/metadata/record">
                <record>
                    <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="name() != ''">
                            <!-- minor issue above: without this I believe I was selecting whitespace and/or other nodes...
                            ...ERROR description: "Supplied element name is a zero-length string" -->
                                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                                    <!-- ACK -->
                                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise/>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </record>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </metadata>
    </xsl:template>
```

**Regarding `<!-- ACK -->`**

As I say above, I believe that the sequence nodes with identical child text is the same in A and B. Thus, for each child node of each record in A, I think that I could use *either* `position()` or `text()` to match the corresponding node in B. But ...

I've tried implementing a key to match the desired metadata/record between A and B (a given ID element value, not shown in examples for XML A and B, could be used to match records).

```
<xsl:key name="match_xml_b" match="record" use="b_id">
...

<xsl:attribute name="dc"
   select="key('match_xml_b', a_id, document('XMLB.xml')/[text() = $a_text]/name()/>

...or...

<xsl:attribute name="dc"
   select="key('match_xml_b', a_id, document('XMLB.xml')/[position() = $a_position]/name()/>
```

I don't think that my syntax is correct for selecting the child node of `record` where text content matches text content from the current node in A (or where position matches that of the current node in A). Additionally, I'm unsure what XPath syntax to use to select *the element name* in B, which is what I need in my **desired output**.

I've also tried some clumsy matching without a key, along the lines of...

```
<xsl:attribute name="dc" 
   select="document('XMLB.xml')/metadata/record[b_id = a_id]/[position() = $a_position]
   (: how to use name() here? :)"/>

or...

<xsl:attribute name="dc" 
   select="document('XMLB.xml')/metadata/record[b_id = a_id]/[text() = $a_text]
   (: how to use name() here? :)"/>
```

...unsuccessfully.

My difficulties here include syntax for matching on a child element of `record` using either `position()` or `text()`, as well as retrieving the *name* of the element once matched.

Comment: Please state which XSLT version you work with.

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen and apologies - XSLT 3.0

Answer (score 2):

If it's permissible to link the elements by matching text, you could do something similar to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="xmlB" select="document('XMLB.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="keyB" match="*" use="text()" />

<xsl:template match="/metadata">
    <metadata>
        <xsl:for-each select="record">
            <record>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:attribute name="dc" select="key('keyB', text(), $xmlB)/name()"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates/>
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </metadata>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This requires XSLT 2.0 or higher.

---

If there are multiple records with identical structure, it might be more efficient to perform the lookup once for the first record, and use the results for all the rest? Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

If both content and position matter you could consider a composite key e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:template match="metadata/record/*">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="dc" select="key('meta-ref', ($pos, string()), $metadata-doc)/local-name()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="meta-ref" match="metadata/record/*" composite="yes">
    <xsl:variable name="pos" as="xs:integer">
      <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$pos, string()"/>
  </xsl:key>
  
  <!-- inlined for testing, use param name="metadata-doc" select="doc('filename.xml')" in your code -->
  <xsl:param name="metadata-doc">
<metadata>
   <record>
      <title>Untitled</title>
      <creator>Gordon Parks</creator>
      <description>An important photograph because (...)</description>
   </record>
   ...
</metadata>    
  </xsl:param>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```